# how to simulate mouse hover on image in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

i have a glow effect written on the hover of an image. this works really good.

my question is

> how to just make itself glitter every 10 seconds without mouse
>   being hovered.

the css classes are like this:

```
.demo
{
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;

    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.005, 1, 1.000, 0); /* older webkit */
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    -o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    transition: all 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600); /* custom */
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.005, 1, 1.000, 0); /* older webkit */
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.005, 1.650, 1.000, -0.600); /* custom */
}

.show-off
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -180px;
    left: -600px;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)100%);
}
.demo:hover .show-off
{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.demo:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px #FFFFFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px #FFFFFF;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px #FFFFFF;
}
```

and the html code is

```
<div id="logo" class="demo">
        <img src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/colourful-logo/18.jpg" />
        <div  class="show-off" />
    </div>
```

i feel i don't have to simulate the mouse hover for achieving the task. any suggestions?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman553/Lomqggee/)

thanks, 
laks.

ps: jquery can be used in case.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for CSS key frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a custom keyframe animation and just set the duration to 10 seconds when you apply it to your image. Add infinite if you want it to repeatedly loop through!

```
@keyframe glow {
    0%{}
    100%{}
}

img {
    animation: glow 10s infinite;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/co9c8qoy/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not do it with CSS. Furthermore you can't do it with JS, because it's not a [trusted event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events).

> Most untrusted events should not trigger default actions, with the
>   exception of the click event.